# Unable to parse JSON in react for post method

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, post

I have a post function where I'm sending a JSON response to the server to change the visibility of an attribute to true/false. The response being sent is in format: 
`{ "keywordId":"KW-0604", "visibility": "False" }`

My post function is as below and is being called within `ComponentWillUpdate()`

```
keyadd(){
     axios.post('http://localhost:8080/visualization/interact/keyword/update', 
    { keywordId: this.state.visible_keywords,  visibility: 'False' })
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
   }
```

For the `keywordId` I'm passing the json string from `this.state.visible_keywords` which I get by splicing data between two tables in our dashboard.

`this.state.visible_keywords` gets the data in format: `[{"keywordId":"KW-0604","keywordName":"Branched-acid biosynthesis"}]` which is a valid JSON response.

However from the above JSON string I only want to send the `keywordID`. I tried using `JSON.stringfy()` and `JSON.parse()` functions but of no success.

With my given set of post function I know the server will respond with an error response.

I've been trying to find a solution for this but in vain.

Regards,

Comment: what is the output of  `console.log(this.state.visible_keywords)`?

Comment: Response from console is `{ keywordId: "KW-0604", keywordName: "Branched-acid biosynthesis" }`

Comment: {keywordId:this.state.visible_keywords[0].keywordId,visibility: 'False'} . Will this not work?? according to what i am understanding

Comment: @stack26 this helped me. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
{keywordId:this.state.visible_keywords[0].keywordId,visibili‌​ty: 'False'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could basically do this way :

```
axios.post('http://localhost:8080/visualization/interact/keyword/update'
        , { keywordId: Object.values(this.state.visible_keywords)[0], visibili‌​ty: 'False'})
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

since

> this.state.visible_keyword

is already JSON, and parsing is useless.

Notice that if you do something like:

```
axios.post('http://..yourURL', this.state.visible_keywords)...
```

is perfectly valid, just confirming what I've said.

Comment: With `Object.values(this.state.visible_keywords)[0]`.  I'm getting the response similar to `this.state.visible_keywords`  .However the problem is solved by using `{keywordId:this.state.visible_keywords[0].keywordId,visibili‌​ty: 'False'} 
` in `axios.post`